# How should python dictionaries be stored in pytables?

Tags: python, dictionary, pytables

pytables doesn't natively support python dictionaries. The way I've approached it is to make a data structure of the form:

```
tables_dict = {
'key'         : tables.StringCol(itemsize=40),
'value'       : tables.Int32Col(),
}
```

(note that I ensure that the keys are <40 characters long) and then create a table using this structure:

```
file_handle.createTable('/', 'dictionary', tables_dict)
```

and then populate it with:

```
file_handle.dictionary.append(dictionary.items())
```

and retrieve data with:

```
dict(file_handle.dictionary.read())
```

This works ok, but reading the dictionary back in is extremely slow. I think the problem is that the `read()` function is causing the entire dictionary to be loaded into memory, which shouldn't really be necessary. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ask PyTables to search inside the table, and also create an index on the key column to speed that up.

To create an index:

```
table.cols.key.createIndex()
```

To query the values where `key` equals the variable `search_key`:

```
[row['value'] for row in table.where('key == search_key')]
```

http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/optimization.html#searchoptim